# How can I exclude archive generated pages from my sitemap?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm using the Jekyll archive plugin to generate blog tag pages and category pages. These pages are being included in my sitemap (I'm using the Jekyll sitemap plugin). Is there any way to exclude these pages from the sitemap?

Because the archive pages are generated automatically by the plugin, any frontmatter solutions are having no effect, is there another way to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

in the front-matter of the post/page you want to exclude, add this:

```
---
sitemap:
  exclude: "yes"
---
```

It needs to be formatted like that, because the conditional statement in the sitemap generator is looking for page.sitemap.exclude=="yes"

In your sitemap.xml file (if you don't use the plugin), you should add this:

```
{% unless page.sitemap.exclude == "yes" or page.name == "feed.xml" %}
```

I have tested it on a custom 404 Page successfully with jekyll!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a front matter variable `sitemap: false` in your archive templates like described in [Jekyll sitemap documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap#exclusions) ?

Comment: I did try that, it doesn't work. I've solved the issue by ditching the sitemap plugin and creating a sitemap.xml file with liquid, which I can control more easily.